# How to cut the string in Oracle sql and return substring

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an requirement in my project where I need to split the url and extract variable from it , url is a column in one of the table. url looks like this

Input Row

```
"http://example.com/wps/myportal/example/viewer?mstrContentType=Report&   mstrId=15F4AC9C4453E5F75456438F732F7B8C&contentName=7.++CTI+Session+Order+Counts&proj=System+Xr+-+DMDR/CW&workspaceName=&woId=&vendorId=Microstrategy"
```

I need o/p as follows to compare with target column as follows

```
ContentType=Report
mstrId=15F4AC9C4453E5F75456438F732F7B8C
contentName=7.++CTI+Session+Order+Counts
etc...
```

I can use only Oracle , should not use programatic language.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the Oracle SQL documentation describing string functions? What have you tried?

Comment: First expected string in the results is `mstrContentType=Report`

Comment: Check out the answer, that I have submitted below with expected result. let us know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here all you need to use, the REGEXP_SUBSTR as below.

```
create table test1(col1 varchar2(4000));
insert into test1 values(
'http://example.com/wps/myportal/example/viewer?mstrContentType=Report&   mstrId=15F4AC9C4453E5F75456438F732F7B8C&contentName=7.++CTI+Session+Order+Counts&proj=System+Xr+-+DMDR/CW&workspaceName=&woId=&vendorId=Microstrategy'
);

select regexp_substr(col1,'[^?"]+',1,2) ss from test1;

select trim(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(col1,'[^?"]+',1,2),'[^&]+', 1, level)) as output_data from test1
connect by regexp_substr(regexp_substr(col1,'[^?"]+',1,2), '[^&]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

**OUTPUT_DATA**

```
mstrContentType=Report
mstrId=15F4AC9C4453E5F75456438F732F7B8C
contentName=7.++CTI+Session+Order+Counts
proj=System+Xr+-+DMDR/CW
workspaceName=
woId=
vendorId=Microstrategy
```

Comment: If information is useful then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your url strings follow a predictable format, you can capture matching portions of the url with [regexp_replace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

```
select regexp_replace(
    regexp_substr(url, '[?&]mstrContentType=([^&]*)')
    '[^=]*=(.*)'
    '\1'
)
```

This will return the value of the `mstrContentType` parameter - the substring to the right of the equals sign but before the next parameter.

Comment: Thank you folks , basically need to get the assigned value to the variable after = .
for eg.
Report
15F4AC9C4453E5F75456438F732F7B8C
7.++CTI+Session+Order+Counts
System+Xr+-+DMDR/CW
null
null
=Microstrategy